How plot ROC curve in r from dismo model.evaluate package
I'm working with dismo package evaluating glm models to Species Distribution Models. I need to plot ROC curve. dismo package have a way to doit using
plot(evaluation, "ROC")

"evaluation" it is a ModelEvaluation class object from "evaluate" function. The curve that I have it's like this 
I extract the TPR and FPR values from this class object like this
ROC.m11.dt=merge(data.frame(TPR= ev_bio1@TPR), 
            data.frame(FPR= ev_bio1@FPR))

and trying too plot it with ggplot, whoever I have this plot,

Both variables are numerics and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm wonder if there a problem with the extraction, because TPR and FPR have 479 observation, but when I merged increase to 229441 observations.

Merging the two data frames fails, because there are no shared column names and you did not specify the argument by. You could just create it with ROC.m11.dt = data.frame(TPR = ev_bio1@TPR, FPR = ev_bio1@FPR).
Providing a reproducible example would help to further pinpoint the problem, if it persists.
